Complex Polynomial relations
I am struggling to find the solution to the problem
Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^2 + ax + b = 0$ and $\beta$ be a root of $x^3 + px + q = 0$. Show that there is a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Q}(a,b,p,q)$ with root $\alpha + \beta$.
My approach:
I tried to use normal binomial theorem. Actually if I write the powers till $6$ of $(\alpha + \beta)$ and place the coefficients in a column then I do get a $6 \times 7$ matrix which states there is a polynomial relation, but to compute the existence of that is quite tedious.
My question:
Is there any alternate simple way to do that ?

Perhaps I’m missing something but wouldn’t the following work?
Let $\alpha_{1,2}$ be the roots of the quadratic and $\beta_{1,2,3}$ be the roots of the cubic. Consider the polynomial
$$
f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^2 ~ \prod_{j=1}^3 (x-\alpha_i-\beta_j).
$$
The roots are of the form $\alpha_i+\beta_j$ for all $i,j$. The coefficients are all symmetric polynomials in $\alpha_i$’s and $\beta_j$’s, so they can be expressed in terms of $a,b,p,q$ via Vieta’s formulas.

Alternatively, we have the system, \begin{align}x+y&=z\x^2+ax+b&=0\y^3+py+q&=0\end{align} or $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns $(x,y,z)$. Eliminating $(x,y)$ using resultants twice (a generalization of Gaussian elimination) easily results in a sextic in $z$. The command in Wolfram Alpha is "Resultant[Resultant[x+y-z,x^2+ax+b,x],y^3+py+q,y]". This approach can be generalized to solve non-linear systems of equations.

the systematic way to do this is to take the companion matrix for the quadratic, which is a 2 by 2, call it $A,$   then companion for the cubic, call it $B,$   finally compute the Kronecker Sum of these,
$$S =  A \otimes I  + I \otimes B $$
The roots of the characteristic polynomial of $S$  are the roots added pairwise.
N.B.  The above is the definition of the sum in Alexander Graham, Kronecker Products   and Matrix Calculus with Applications. The definition in Horn and Johnson is different as far as ordering. Either way, we get that the eigenvalues of the sum are the pairwise sums of the eigenvalues of $A,B.$
Explicitly :
$$\pmatrix{0&-b\\1&-a}\otimes\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}+\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}\otimes\pmatrix{0&0&-q\\1&0&-p\\0&1&0}=$$
$$\pmatrix{0&0&-q&-b&0&0\\1&0&-p&0&-b&0\\0&1&0&0&0&-b\\1&0&0&-a&0&-q\\0&1&0&1&-a&-p\\0&0&1&0&1&-a}$$
Sage program :
 var('a b p q')
 M1=matrix([[0,-b],[1,-a]])
 M2=matrix([[0,0,-q],[1,0,-p],[0,1,0]])
 M3=M1.tensor_product(identity_matrix(3))
 +identity_matrix(2).tensor_product(M2)
 show(M3)
 c=M3.charpoly()
 show(c)    

I did get the final sextic with all variables. I also made an example with all integer roots. $a = -3, b = 2, p = -37, q = -84.$  The quadratic is $x^2 -3x+2 = (x-1)(x-2)$  The cubic is
$x^3 - 37x - 84 = (x-7)(x+3)(x+4).$  The six roots should be $8, -2, -3, 9, -1, -2$ alright, double root. Anyway
$$  x^6 - 9x^5 - 41x^4 + 213x^3 + 1192x^2 + 1812x + 864
  $$
With general $a,b,p,q$
$$x^6  + 3a x^5 + (3a^2 + 3b+2p)x^4 +(a^3 +6ab + 4ap)x^3 +
  (3a^2 b  + 3 b^2 + 3a^2 p + 3aq + p^2) x^2 +    
( 3ab^2 + a^3 p + a p^2 + 3 a^2 q -6bq + 2 pq ) x +
(b^3 + a^2 bp - 2b^2 p  + b p^2 + a^3 q - 3abq +apq + q^2)  $$

From Horn and Johnson, Topics in Matrix Analysis:


How extraordinary is this solution ! Although I have been working with companion matrices and Kronecker products, I had no idea of such a result. Do you have references ?

@JeanMarie   Hello!  I bought a little book called Kronecker Products  and Matrix Calculus,  by  Alexander Graham. I have it around somewhere.

Thanks, I am going to look for this book...

@JeanMarie  It is also in Horn and Johnson (1991), Topics in Matrix Analysis,   I will send you a pdf if I can find your email.

Besides, would you mind if I insert an explicit computation in your answer that I have just done with Sage, free for you to modify/suppress whatever you want ?

@JeanMarie  Go Ahead!

@JeanMarie   Very Good.   I will leave it be. Did the email work?

Yes. Thanks again.
